# Minimax Algorithm with TicTacToe (But each player can only have 3 tacs on board)

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I am currently making a TicTacToe game that uses a Minimax algorithm for Player vs Computer. As of right now, the code only has Hard mode on PvE. It is a working bot that you cant win against using Minimax algorithm. However, I need to find a way to incorporate a special rule...

Each player is only allowed to have 3 'tacs' on the board at a time. Once they reach 3, they have to move a tac from one spot to another. I am not entirely sure how to implement this, could someone give me some ideas?

```
"""
TicTacToe - 3 symbols max
By Gage Gunn (???), Trevor Purta (Player vs. Computer), Toby Howie (Player vs. Player), Rachel Powers (Computer vs. Computer)
"""

# -------- Modules --------

import os
import time
import random

# -------- Global Variables --------

human = 'O'
bot = 'X'
amount_of_x = 0
amount_of_o = 0
ID = '' #Detecting which game mode (PvP, PvE, EvE)
ID2 = '' #Detecting which difficulty in PvE
ID3 = '' #Detecting which difficulty in EvE

# -------- Functions --------

def printBoard(board):
  print(board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3] + '        1 | 2 | 3')
  print(board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6] + '        4 | 5 | 6')
  print(board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9] + '        7 | 8 | 9')
  print('\n')


def spaceIsFree(position):
  if board[position] == ' ':
    return True
  else:
    return False


def insertLetter(letter, position):
  if spaceIsFree(position):
    board[position] = letter
    printBoard(board)
    if (checkDraw()):
      print("Draw!")
      exit()
    if checkForWin():
        if letter == 'X':
          print("Bot wins!")
          exit()
        else:
          print("Player wins!")
          exit()

    return


  else:
    print("Can't insert there!")
    position = int(input("Please enter new position:  "))
    insertLetter(letter, position)
    return


def checkForWin():
  if (board[1] == board[2] and board[1] == board[3] and board[1] != ' '):
    return True
  elif (board[4] == board[5] and board[4] == board[6] and board[4] != ' '):
    return True
  elif (board[7] == board[8] and board[7] == board[9] and board[7] != ' '):
    return True
  elif (board[1] == board[4] and board[1] == board[7] and board[1] != ' '):
    return True
  elif (board[2] == board[5] and board[2] == board[8] and board[2] != ' '):
    return True
  elif (board[3] == board[6] and board[3] == board[9] and board[3] != ' '):
    return True
  elif (board[1] == board[5] and board[1] == board[9] and board[1] != ' '):
    return True
  elif (board[7] == board[5] and board[7] == board[3] and board[7] != ' '):
    return True
  else:
    return False


def checkWhichMarkWon(mark):
  if board[1] == board[2] and board[1] == board[3] and board[1] == mark:
    return True
  elif (board[4] == board[5] and board[4] == board[6] and board[4] == mark):
    return True 
  elif (board[7] == board[8] and board[7] == board[9] and board[7] == mark):
    return True
  elif (board[1] == board[4] and board[1] == board[7] and board[1] == mark):
    return True
  elif (board[2] == board[5] and board[2] == board[8] and board[2] == mark):
    return True
  elif (board[3] == board[6] and board[3] == board[9] and board[3] == mark):
    return True
  elif (board[1] == board[5] and board[1] == board[9] and board[1] == mark):
    return True
  elif (board[7] == board[5] and board[7] == board[3] and board[7] == mark):
    return True
  else:
    return False


def checkDraw():
  for key in board.keys():
    if (board[key] == ' '):
      return False
  return True


def playerMove():
  position = int(input("Enter the position for 'O':  "))
  insertLetter(human, position)
  return


def compMove():
  bestScore = -800
  bestMove = 0
  for key in board.keys():
    if (board[key] == ' '):
      board[key] = bot
      score = minimax(board, 0, False)
      board[key] = ' '
      if (score > bestScore):
        bestScore = score
        bestMove = key

  insertLetter(bot, bestMove)
  return


def minimax(board, depth, isMaximizing):
  if (checkWhichMarkWon(bot)):
    return 1
  elif (checkWhichMarkWon(human)):
    return -1
  elif (checkDraw()):
    return 0

  if (isMaximizing):
    bestScore = -800
    for key in board.keys():
      if (board[key] == ' '):
        board[key] = bot
        score = minimax(board, depth + 1, False)
        board[key] = ' '
        if (score > bestScore):
          bestScore = score
    return bestScore

  else:
    bestScore = 800
    for key in board.keys():
      if (board[key] == ' '):
        board[key] = human
        score = minimax(board, depth + 1, True)
        board[key] = ' '
        if (score < bestScore):
          bestScore = score
    return bestScore


board = {1: ' ', 2: ' ', 3: ' ',
        4: ' ', 5: ' ', 6: ' ',
        7: ' ', 8: ' ', 9: ' '}

def pick_game_type(): #Pick PvP, PvE, EvE
  global ID
  print("""
First, Pick which game mode you would like to play!
(Player vs. Player [1], Player vs. Computer [2], Computer vs. Computer [3])
  """)
  type_choice = input('> ')
  if type_choice == "1": #Set global ID for [1]
    ID = "1"
  elif type_choice == "2": #Set global ID for [2]
    ID = "2"
  elif type_choice == "3": #Set global ID for [3]
    ID = "3"

# -------- Script --------

os.system('cls') #Clear console
print("""
Welcome to Wacky Tacky Toe, Tac, Tic!
By Gage Gunn, Trevor Purta, Toby Howie, and Rachel Power with an s
""")

pick_game_type() #Choose gamemode

if ID == '1': #PvP Chosen
  pass

elif ID == '2': #PvE Chosen
  os.system('cls')

  print('''
Welcome to Player vs Computer! In this version of Tic, Tac, Toe, each player can have a maximum of 3 tacs on the board at a time!
Decide which difficuly you would like to play? (Easy [1] or Hard [2])''')
  ID2 = input('> ')

  valid_input = False
  while not valid_input: #Checks validity of ID2
    if ID2 in ['1', '2']:
      valid_input = True
    else:
      ID2 = input('> ')
  
  if ID2 == '1': #Easy was chosen
    pass

  elif ID2 == '2':
    print('You have chosen hard! You are X, the computer is O. The computer will go first')
    while not checkForWin():
      compMove()
      playerMove()

elif ID == '3': #PvE Chosen
  pass
```

Comment: This is rather broad. Where are you stuck, specifically? The minimax algorithm will be exactly the same regardless of whether the rule about moving pieces after 3 exists or not -- that's taken care of by the TTT move generator procedure. Minimax just says, "give me all of the legal moves for this position" and applies them one at a time, regardless of what the moves are. The problem here is your move generation is too tightly coupled with the minimax routine -- I suggest decoupling it to an API like `get_moves()` that MM can invoke.

Comment: You will also need to define a rule (or maximum depth, or pattern tracking) to prevent the minimax move expansion from getting into infinite loops of players moving their tacs back and forth into repeated patterns.

Comment: I'm stuck on where to include that very specific rule, coupled with the bot still making the most optimal choice. I'm fairly new to minimax, so this is sort of a first go at it you know? I guess I got my terms mixed in with each other haha. So when you say decouple it, do you mean to make the moving procedure more standalone that the minimax takes from? What's an example I could look into for a better idea/understanding? (Thank you for your input by the way, I really appreciate it :) )

@ggorlen

Comment: That is very true! I could see scenarios where the player and bot could both get into a loop as such! Thank you, I would have never thought about that 

@AlainT.

Comment: This is in Java, but see [this](https://gist.github.com/ggorlen/f02a0d7c32e4ac1a289246e35e1ff9bc#file-ttt-java-L123) and [this](https://gist.github.com/ggorlen/f02a0d7c32e4ac1a289246e35e1ff9bc#file-ttt-java-L37) for an example of a function that returns legal moves for the MM algorithm to iterate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to isolate components of gameplay into reusable functions that can be combined to simulate moves for the minimax calculations.

Because you need simulations, it is a good idea to have a self contained data structure that represents the sate of the game (board) including who's turn it is to play (i'm using a 10 character string where the first character is the current player and the other 9 are the current state of the board).

The first thing you'll need to implement is a function to simulate a move (returning a new game state):

```
def playMove(game,toPos,fromPos):
    played =  [game[0] if i==toPos else "." if i==fromPos else p
               for i,p in enumerate(game)]
    return "".join(played)
```

You will also need a function to switch the current player.  This needs to be separate so that you can easily evaluate the outcome for the current player before simulating the opponent's moves:

```
def switchPlayer(game):
    return "XO"[game[0]=="X"]+game[1:]  # returns a new game state
```

In order to recursively simulate moves, you'll need a function that gives a list of possible moves.  Given your gameplay rules, a move is defined as a target position (toPos) and an optional origin position (fromPos).  for the first 3 moves there will be no origin (lets make fromPos = toPos for those)

```
def getMoves(game):
    player,*board = game
    moves = [(i,i) for i,p in enumerate(board,1) if p=="."]  # 1st 3 moves
    if board.count(player)==3:                               # moves 4+
        origins = [r for r,p in enumerate(board,1) if p==player ]
        moves   = [ (i,r) for i,_ in moves for r in origins] # add origins
    return moves
```

For simulations and actual gameplay, you'll need a function to determine if the game is won:

```
winPatterns = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9),(1,5,9),(3,5,7)]
def isWin(game):
    return any(all(game[i]==game[0] for i in p) for p in winPatterns)
```

Rating the outcome of a move could be some complex formula but, to keep it simple, let's just say that winning is 1 and not winning is zero. The minimax function will recursively simulate moves giving them a rating based on the "nearest" conclusive move (1 for wins, -1 for losses).

```
maxDepth = 6       # maximum depth = computer's skill
memo = dict()      # memoization (for performance)
def minimax(game,depth=maxDepth):
    if (game,depth) in memo:      # known rating at this depth 
        return memo[game,depth]   
    if isWin(game): return 1      # no moves after a win (base condition)
    if not depth: return 0        # limit depth (avoids infinite loops)
    oGame  = switchPlayer(game)   # will simulate opponent's moves
    oRatings = []                 # opponent's minimax ratings
    for move in getMoves(oGame):   
        played = playMove(oGame,*move)           # simulate
        oRatings.append(minimax(played,depth-1)) # get rating    
    rating = -max(oRatings or [1])               # worst countermove
    for d in range(1,depth+1):
        memo[game,d]=rating    # memorize for this depth and lower
    return rating
```

*Because the game data structure is hashable (i.e. a string), it can be used for memoization which greatly increases performance of the minimax function.*

With the minimax function, you can determine the best move to make for the computer player (the one with the highest minimax rating):

```
def bestMove(game):
    return max(getMoves(game),key=lambda m:minimax(playMove(game,*m)))
```

*You could shuffle the moves before getting the max() to randomize selection of the best move when more than one move has the highest rating*

Putting it all together in a gameplay loop:

```
def printBoard(game):
    for r in range(1,10,3):
          print("("+") (".join(game[r:r+3])+")",list(range(r,r+3)))

from random import sample
while True:
    player,computer = sample("XOXO",2) # random starter, random computer
    game = player + "."*9
    while True:
        printBoard(game)
        if isWin(game): break
        game = switchPlayer(game)
        player = game[0]
        if player == computer:
            toPos,fromPos = bestMove(game)
            print(f"Computer plays {player} at {toPos}",end=" ")
            print(f"from {fromPos}"*(fromPos!=toPos))
        else:
            strMoves = [(str(t),str(f)) for t,f in getMoves(game)]
            while True:
                fromPos = toPos = input(f"Position to play for {player}: ")
                if not toPos in (f for f,_ in strMoves):
                    print("invalid position"); continue
                if game[1:].count(player)<3: break
                fromPos = input(f"Position to remove {player} from: ")
                if (toPos,fromPos) not in strMoves:
                    print("invalid move")
                else: break
        game = playMove(game,int(toPos),int(fromPos))
    print( f"{player}'s WIN !!!\n")
    if input("play again (y/n)") != "y": break
    print()
```

Sample Run:

```
(.) (.) (.) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (.) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 5 
(.) (.) (.) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 1
(X) (.) (.) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 3 
(X) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 7
(X) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 4 
(X) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(O) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 6
(X) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(O) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 9 from 3
(X) (.) (.) [1, 2, 3]
(O) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (O) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 3
Position to remove X from: 7
(X) (.) (X) [1, 2, 3]
(O) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (.) (O) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 2 from 4
(X) (O) (X) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (.) (O) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 8
Position to remove X from: 3
(X) (O) (.) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (X) (O) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 3 from 2
(X) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (X) (O) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 7
Position to remove X from: 8
(X) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (O) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 4 from 9
(X) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(O) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (.) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 
Position to play for X: 9
Position to remove X from: 1
(.) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(O) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (X) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 8 from 4
(.) (.) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (X) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (O) (X) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 2
Position to remove X from: 6
(.) (X) (O) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (O) (X) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 1 from 3
(O) (X) (.) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (O) (X) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 3
Position to remove X from: 7
(O) (X) (X) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (.) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (O) (X) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 6 from 8
(O) (X) (X) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (O) [4, 5, 6]
(.) (.) (X) [7, 8, 9]
Position to play for X: 7
Position to remove X from: 2
(O) (.) (X) [1, 2, 3]
(.) (O) (O) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (X) [7, 8, 9]
Computer plays O at 4 from 1
(.) (.) (X) [1, 2, 3]
(O) (O) (O) [4, 5, 6]
(X) (.) (X) [7, 8, 9]
O's WIN !!!

play again (y/n) ? n
```

Comment: Just tried this out and it works flawlessly! This is very concise and quite honestly a beautiful piece of code. I have a lot to learn from this :)