# Evaluating all possible board states within a minimax algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, matrix, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I am working on writing a connect 4 game as well as a minimax algorithm to play against. I am currently writing and implementing the minimax algorithm. Right now I am just trying to print out all possible board states up to a certain depth, which I think is the hard part of the algorithm. I will then write in the part of the algorithm that determines whether to maximize or minimize, and from there it should be more or less finished. This is what I have currently and I have annotated the code to explain what each line does

```
#I realize there will need to be an argument here determining whether to maximize or minimize, I 
#will implement that after this works.
def minimax(board,depth):
  #when I reach my target depth, return the board and print it
  if depth == 0:
    printboard(board)
    return board
#For all of my possible moves, set the move, recursively call minimax until it hits target depth
#at which point the board state will be printed, and then undo the last set move so that the 
#for loop can continue from previous board state
  for move in possiblemoves(board):
    setmove(move, board, turn)
    minimax(board,depth - 1)
    setmove(move, board, -1)

#call the fuction on an empty board, and do a depth of 2
minimax(board,2)
```

When I call this function, the first board output looks proper

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
['X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

but the second state, which should be an X in the bottom of the 1st and 2nd column. I am not sure where this issue is coming from, but I think it is removing the very first move set in place, instead of the second move, because the second board state looks like

```
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', 'X', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

If you have any advice on how to fix this algorithm so that the proper amount of board states will be outputted, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294400/5237560) for an example of a minimax based tic-tac-toe game.  The board and game rules are different but the approach should apply pretty much as-is

Comment: The code you've shown looks like it could work, so perhaps the problem is in the code you haven't shown. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Although inefficient but to keep things simple, each time you recursively pass the board, pass a copy of the board. The alternative is to undo the last move upon returning from a recursive call.